# Failed to login, Forbidden, using hawtio offline war file with ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I'm trying to use hawtio 1.5.2 offline war file as a webapp within ActiveMQ 5.14.5.  I have added what I believe are the required entries to ACTIVEMQ_OPTS in $ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/env

-Dhawtio.role=admins -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config

and when I go to http://localhost:8161/hawtio I get the login screen, but after using admin/admin and trying to login I get the error Failed to login, forbidden.

I am however able to use the executable JAR for hawtio and connect to my server, so I believe I must be missing something in the ActiveMQ configuration to allow this to work.

I have tried adding log4j.logger.io.hawt=DEBUG to my ActiveMQ's log4j.properties file but I don't seem to get any feedback in the logs from hawtio.

Can anyone help?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.  I didn't have this entry in `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS` in `$ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin/env`

```
-Dhawtio.realm=activemq
```

Now with my entry reading

```
ACTIVEMQ_OPTS="$ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY \
    -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties \
    -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ACTIVEMQ_CONF/login.config \
    -Dhawtio.realm=activemq \
    -Dhawtio.role=admins \
    -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal"
```

I'm able to login.